# Como cargar diccionario pesado en python sin errores de memoria al ejecutar

Tags: python, diccionarios, data

Tengo un diccionario en una archivo .pkl que tiene los nombres de numeros como clave y su numero literal como valor, al querer guardar todos los datos en un diccionario en python y ejecutar el script, se me detiene el proceso por problemas de memoria, como podria hacer para manejar esa gran cantidad de datos en un diccionario sin que me de ese error?, o alguna otra sugerencia que sea tan eficiente como el diccionario en python?
Este seria el ejemplo de mi codigo implementado hasta el momento, en el se ingresa un texto y lo que me deberia devolver es el mismo texto pero en los nombres de numeros me devuelve el numero literal en vez del nombre.
Ejemplo:
si escribo "**hay nueve millones de dólares**" me deberia devolver "**hay 9,000,000 de dólares**"

**nota: mi archivo .pkl actual tiene un peso de 7gb**

```
import pickle
import re

def cargar_diccionario():
    print('cargando dic')
    try:
        with open("diccionarios/mi_diccionario.pkl", "rb") as archivo:
            return pickle.load(archivo)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

def reemplazar_numeros_en_texto(texto, diccionario):
    print('compilando dic')
    # Crear una expresión regular para buscar los nombres de números
    patron = re.compile(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(diccionario.keys()) + r')\b', re.IGNORECASE)

    print('reemplazando text')
    # Reemplazar los nombres de números por sus valores
    texto_reemplazado = patron.sub(lambda m: str(diccionario[m.group(0).lower()]), texto)

    return texto_reemplazado

texto_original = "hay nueve millones de dólares"
diccionario = cargar_diccionario()
texto_reemplazado = reemplazar_numeros_en_texto(texto_original, diccionario)
print(texto_reemplazado)
```

Comment: Escribe una función que reciba el texto y lo convierta a valor entero. Te evitas leer el archivo y mantenerlo en memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor cambiar de enfoque, creando una función que reciba un texto, lo analice y convierta a valor numérico. A continuación un esbozo de la solución.

Primero, tenemos un diccionario acotado a las palabras/expresiones básicas: del 1 al 100, más las centenas.

```
nombres = {
    "un" : 1,
    "uno": 1,
    "dos": 2,
    "tres": 3,
    "cuatro": 4,
    "diez": 10,
    "veinte": 20,
    "veintiuno": 21,
    "veinte y un": 21,
    "veinte y uno": 21,
    "veinte y dos": 22,
    "noventa y nueve": 99,
    "cien": 100,
    "doscientos": 200,
    "trescientos": 300,
    "quinientos": 500
}
```

El diccionario puede contener más de una forma para el mismo valor ("veintiuno", "veinte y uno").

**Primera parte: Convertir textos a numeros por separado.**

Usando como ejemplo *"doscientos veinte y dos mil millones trescientos cuatro mil quinientos veinte"*, primero tomamos el texto y lo separamos usando la palabra "millones" en subexpresiones que van de 1 a 999.999. Es para simplificar el tratamiento posterior.

Esto nos da dos subexpresiones: *doscientos veinte y dos mil* y *trescientos cuatro mil quinientos veinte*, que convertiremos por separado.

Para convertir buscamos en cada subexpresión el nombre más largo posible. Ejemplo: en la primera subexpresión encontremos "veinte" primero y luego "veinte y dos".  Encontrada el nombre más largo, reemplazamos el texto ("veinte y dos") por el número (como texto), y nos da "doscientos 22 mil".

El proceso se repite hasta que no haya nada más que reemplazar. Eso nos deja "200 22 mil". Notese que "mil" y "millones" no están en el diccionario, pues funcionan como multiplicadores, no como valores.

**Segunda parte: sumar los numeros.**

Ahora recorremos los subtextos ya convertidos extrayendo los valores, sumandolos y aplicando los multiplicadores correspondientes ("mil", "millones").

La subexpresión *200 22 mil* produce (200+22) * 1000.
La subexpresión *300 4 mil 500 20* produce (300+4) * 1000 + 500 + 20.

El resultado final se obtiene multiplicando la primera subexpresión por un millón y sumando la segunda.

**Código**

```
nombres = {
    "un" : 1,
    "uno": 1,
    "dos": 2,
    "tres": 3,
    "cuatro": 4,
    "diez": 10,
    "veinte": 20,
    "veintiuno": 21,
    "veinte y un": 21,
    "veinte y uno": 21,
    "veinte y dos": 22,
    "noventa y nueve": 99,
    "cien": 100,
    "doscientos": 200,
    "trescientos": 300,
    "quinientos": 500
}


def text2int(texto: str) -> int:
    valor = 0
    for subtexto in texto.split("millones"):
        valor *= 1_000_000
        #   Primera parte: convertir subexpresiones
        #   delimitadas por "mil", "millones"
        while True:
            found = ''
            for key in nombres.keys():
                if subtexto.find(key) >= 0:
                    if len(key) > len(found):
                        found = key
            if found:
                subtexto = subtexto.replace(found, str(nombres[found]))
            else:
                break

        #   Segunda parte: Sumar las cifras y aplicar miles/millones
        subvalor = 0
        for palabra in subtexto.split():
            if palabra.isnumeric():
                subvalor += int(palabra)
            elif palabra == "mil":
                subvalor *= 1000
        valor += subvalor
    return valor

prueba = "doscientos veinte y dos mil millones trescientos cuatro mil quinientos veinte"
print(f"{text2int(prueba):_d}")
```

lo que nos da

```
222_000_304_520

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Nota: es una solución incompleta, suboptima y puede tener errores.

**Anexo: Solución General**

Dado un texto del tipo

*La comuna tiene una superficie de ciento veintres km2 y una población de cuarenta y dos mil habitantes*

queremos convertilo en

*La comuna tiene una superficie de 123 km2 y una población de 42.000 habitates*

Una solución es identificar las secuencias "numéricas" en el texto. Esto implica examinar cada palabra para identificar las "numéricas". Hint: ver si la palabra es una llave de `datos` o una palabra como "mil", "millón".

Teniendo catalogadas las palabras, se pueden extraer las secuencias numéricas completas, como "ciento veintres", convertirlas a numeros usando `text2int` y reemplazarlas en el texto original.

Comment: No puedo reproducir el código, ya que no está definida la variable textos. Segundo, me parece que el OP necesita obtener números dentro de un texto en el cual no todas las palabras son números. Cito su ejemplo: "hay nueve millones de dólares". No lo pude probar, pero sospecho que el código fallaría en ese punto.

Comment: @DanteS. Corregido. Donde dice "textos" debe decir "nombres".

Comment: @DanteS. Cómo dije, no es la solución completa. Le di el punto de partida, de ahí que siga adelante.

Answer (score 0):

Incluso sin el problema del diccionario, tu regex sería demasiado extensa para la memoria de la pc. Una forma sería recurrir a una base de datos... oooo...

Los números se escriben con ciertas reglas. Podemos usar estas reglas para detectar patrones que nos permitirán identificar los números en un texto. Para esto, ya no nos sirven las expresiones regulares.

En su lugar, primero creamos los diccionarios con los números que son independientes a las reglas antes mencionadas, por ejemplo las unidades y los números cuya decena es 1 ("dieces")

```
UNIDADES = {"UNO":1,
            "DOS":2,
            "TRES":3,
            "CUATRO":4,
            "CINCO":5,
            "SEIS":6,
            "SIETE":7,
            "OCHO":8,
            "NUEVE":9}

DIECES = {"DIEZ":10,
          "ONCE":11,
          "DOCE":12,
          "TRECE":13,
          "CATORCE":14,
          "QUINCE":15,
          "DIECISEIS":16,
          "DIECISIETE":17,
          "DIECIOCHO":18,
          "DIECINUEVE":19}
```

Luego creamos una clase `Scanner` encargada de parsear los números. A esa clase, le vamos a pasar una cadena, pasar a mayusculas para evitar falsos negativos (ejemplo "diez" en minusculas) y separamos cada palabra. En el ejemplo, vamos a usar split(), pero podés usar una regex para eso.

Junto a esta lista, vamos a guardar un cursor (un número indicando la posición de la palabra a procesar). Y si se trata de un número valido, reemplazar la sección procesada por el número en cuestión. Si no es valido, hacer que la función que parsea el número devuelva None, indicando que analize desde la proxima palabra.

##### Código

A continuación, un código que parsea hasta el número 999.

```
UNIDADES = {"UNO":1,
            "DOS":2,
            "TRES":3,
            "CUATRO":4,
            "CINCO":5,
            "SEIS":6,
            "SIETE":7,
            "OCHO":8,
            "NUEVE":9}

DIECES = {"DIEZ":10,
          "ONCE":11,
          "DOCE":12,
          "TRECE":13,
          "CATORCE":14,
          "QUINCE":15,
          "DIECISEIS":16,
          "DIECISIETE":17,
          "DIECIOCHO":18,
          "DIECINUEVE":19}

VEINTES = {f"VENTI{key}":20 + value for key, value in UNIDADES.items()} 

DECENAS = {"DIEZ":10,
           "VEINTE":20,
           "TREINTA":30,
           "CUARENTA":40,
           "CINCUENTA":50,
           "SESENTA":60,
           "SETENTA":70,
           "OCHENTA":80,
           "NOVENTA":90}

CENTENAS = {"CIEN":100,
            "DOSCIENTOS":200,
            "TRESCIENTOS":300,
            "CUATROCIENTOS":400,
            "QUINIENTOS":500,
            "SEISCIENTOS":600,
            "SETECIENTOS":700,
            "OCHOCIENTOS":800,
            "NOVECIENTOS":900}

class Scanner:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text.upper().split()
        self.pos = 0

    def scan_unidad(self):
        unidad = UNIDADES.get(self.text[self.pos])

        if unidad is not None:
            self.pos += 1
            return unidad
        
    def scan_decena(self):
        # Si se trata de un número con decena 1... #
        num = DIECES.get(self.text[self.pos])

        if num is not None:
            self.pos += 1
            return num

        # Si se trata de un número con decena 2...
        num = VEINTES.get(self.text[self.pos])

        if num is not None:
            self.pos += 1
            return num
        
        # Si no...
        dec = DECENAS.get(self.text[self.pos])

        if dec is not None:
            self.pos += 2
            unit = self.scan_unidad()

            # Si unit es None, asumimos que es 0
            if unit is None:
                unit = 0
            # sumamos la decena (ej: 40) con la unidad (ej:5)
            return dec + unit
        
        # Si no es una decena, probamos si es una unidad
        return self.scan_unidad()

    def scan_centena(self):
        # Los números de centena 1 empiezan por "ciento".
        cent = 100 if self.text[self.pos] == "CIENTO" else CENTENAS.get(self.text[self.pos])

        if cent is not None:
            self.pos += 1
            # Obtenemos la decena
            dec = self.scan_decena()

            # si dec es None, asumimos que se trata de 0
            if dec is None:
                dec = 0
            return cent + dec
        
        return self.scan_decena()
    
    def sub(self):
        # Mientras no hayamos terminado de analizar la lista
        while self.pos < len(self.text):
            # guardo la posición inicial del hipotetico número antes de que cambie     
            start = self.pos

            # aquí se llama a la función encargada de procesar el número más grande posible
            # en este caso la centena
            res = self.scan_centena()

            # Si 
            if res is None:
                self.pos += 1
            else:
                # Reemplazamos la parte de la lista entre start y self.pos por el número
                self.text[start:self.pos] = [str(res)]
            
        return " ".join(self.text)
    
textos = [
    "hay cheques de novecientos noventa y dolares y diez pesos",
    "hay cuarenta y nueve dolares y un cheque de novecientos noventa y nueve pesos",
    "hay novecientos dolares"
]

for texto in textos:
    print(Scanner(texto).sub())
```

**Produce**

```
HAY CHEQUES DE 990 DOLARES Y 10 PESOS
HAY 49 DOLARES Y UN CHEQUE DE 999 PESOS
HAY 900 DÓLARES
```

---

**Nota** El código publicado podría tener errores no detectados. Además, está destinada a ser un ejemplo que cubra el caso de palabras no consideradas números entre los números. Cualquier implementación adicional es tarea para el lector.
Adicionalmente, esto no es un interprete del lenguaje natural, las ambiguedades en el texto, ejemplo `NNÓVENTA` no son detectadas.